# Android 10 How to change date_taken by current time when insert into media?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I inserted a video into media store but after insert my gallery sort wrong order because date_taken it's not current time , system using time created in metadata of video. How I can change date_taken to current time in media store or in metadata ?

ExifInterface can edit date_created in metadata but it' is only support JPEG .

This is code I used to insert video

```
        ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE, title);
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED, Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));                     
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.MIME_TYPE, MIME_TYPE_VIDEO);
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, EnvironmentWrappper.RELATIVE_PATH_VIDEO);
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.SIZE, outputFile.length());

        long duration = 0;
        List<Metadata> metadataList = VideoPreviewMetadataManager.loadMetaDataLite(outputPath);
        if (metadataList != null && !metadataList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Metadata metadata : metadataList) {
                if (ZMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION.equals(metadata.getKey())) {
                    duration = Long.parseLong(metadata.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
        }
        contentvalues.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION, duration);
        try {
            Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentvalues);

             FileLocalUriWrapper file = new FileLocalUriWrapper(outputPath);
             OutputStream fos = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
             InputStream inputStream = file.getFileInputStream();
             IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, fos);
             fos.close();
             inputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have the real machine of androidQ, I use the results of the simulator test, it seems that DATE_TAKEN this property has no effect in androidQ, and even many times it is NULL.

So I get the time attribute in androidQ before according to DATA_TAKEN, AndroidQ later according to ADD_DATE.

---

Of course, this is just my own experience, different devices, devices that may be upgraded from api28 to 29 may be retained in the MediaStore.